# Countifs does not work when a range with multiple column is selected

Tags: excel

I need a count if function that counts me the cells that meet a certain criteria. This should be done with countifs. The formula is the following:
`=COUNTIFS(Orders!D:D;"*Ecolab*";Orders!B:B;">=01/01/2019";Orders!U:U;">=36";Orders!K:Q;">=1")`This formula returns me an value type error.

This formula works well until I introduce the last condition `orders!K:Q;">=1"`
I would like a formula that counts if the word Ecolab is present in the cell; if the date is after or equal 01/01/2019; if the column U has more or equal than the number 36 and if there is at least a "1" in the cells in the row from column K to column Q. I could do this by easily replicating the countifs several times, (i.e `=COUNTIFS(Orders!D:D;"*Ecolab*";Orders!B:B;">=01/01/2019";Orders!U:U;">=36";Orders!K:K;">=1")+COUNTIFS(Orders!D:D;"*Ecolab*";Orders!B:B;">=01/01/2019";Orders!U:U;">=36";Orders!L:L;">=1")+...........+COUNTIFS(Orders!D:D;"*Ecolab*";Orders!B:B;">=01/01/2019";Orders!U:U;">=36";Orders!Q:Q;">=1")` 
But I would rather not include such a long formula as it would create confusion for the ultimate user of the excel sheet

Comment: COUNTIFS only works with ranges that are the same size and shape. You'd have to use another function like SUMPRODUCT, or use an array of column offsets with OFFSET for the last range.

Comment: Are you saying that if K1 and M1 are both greater than 1 then the count for row 1 should be 2?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, you could use SUMPRODUCT (avoid using whole columns for that) or an array with OFFSET like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Orders!D:D;"*Ecolab*";Orders!B:B;">=01/01/2019";Orders!U:U;">=36";OFFSET(Orders!J:J;0;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7});">=1"))
```

Comment: Yes, which is the same as the multiple COUNTIFs result the OP suggested he/she could use. If that's not the desired result, then the OP needs to clarify...

Comment: If K1, L1, M1, N1, O1, P1 and Q1 are all >=1, isn't that row counted 7 times?

Comment: @user11314630 Again, yes - see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If the count for K:Q should be 1 when there may be more than one cell greater or equal to 1 in a single row then you need to apply OR criteria in a SUMPRODUCT.

SUMPRODUCT formulas should not use full column references; there is too much wasted calculation. The following is for rows 2:99; adjust for your own use.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ecolab", Orders!D2:D99)),
            --(Orders!B2:B99>=DATE(2019, 1, 1)),
            --(Orders!U2:U99>=36),
            SIGN((Orders!K2:K99>=1)+(Orders!L2:L99>=1)+(Orders!M2:M99>=1)+(Orders!N2:N99>=1)+(Orders!O2:O99>=1)+(Orders!P2:P99>=1)+(Orders!Q2:Q99>=1)))
```

Comment: Little shorter would be: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ecolab", Orders!D2:D99))*(Orders!B2:B99>=DATE(2019, 1, 1))*(Orders!U2:U99>=36)*(K2:Q99>=1))`

Comment: That produces padded results as well. Using SIGN to convert any number from 1 to 7 back to 1 is the best way I know for a SUMPRODUCT OR statement. Well, either SIGN or collectively greater than 0.